# could not convert string to float in python

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, scikit-learn, anaconda, pca

i try to analysis the Principle Component from cvs file but when i run the code i get this error

> C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop>python pca.py
>
> ValueError: could not convert string to float: Annee;NET;INT;SUB;LMT;DCT;IMM;EXP;VRD

this is my cvs file

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

i try to remove any space and any think
this is my python script, i don't know what i miss

Note: i run this code under python2.7

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib  
import numpy as np  
import glob  
import os  
import time  
import numpy

my_matrix = numpy.loadtxt(open("pca.csv","rb"),delimiter= ",",skiprows=0)  
def pca(dataMat, r, autoset_r=False, autoset_rate=0.9): 
    """
    purpose: principal components analysis
    """  
    print("Start to do PCA...") 
    t1 = time.time() 
    meanVal = np.mean(dataMat, axis=0)  
    meanRemoved = dataMat - meanVal  
    # normData = meanRemoved / np.std(dataMat)  
    covMat = np.cov(meanRemoved, rowvar=0)    
    eigVals, eigVects = np.linalg.eig(np.mat(covMat)) 
    eigValIndex = np.argsort(-eigVals)  


    if autoset_r:
        r = autoset_eigNum(eigVals, autoset_rate)
        print("autoset: take top {} of {} features".format(r, meanRemoved.shape[1]))

    r_eigValIndex = eigValIndex[:r]  
    r_eigVect = eigVects[:, r_eigValIndex]  
    lowDDataMat = meanRemoved * r_eigVect  
    reconMat = (lowDDataMat * r_eigVect.T) + meanVal    
    t2 = time.time()   
    print("PCA takes %f seconds" %(t2-t1))
    joblib.dump(r_eigVect, './pca_args_save/r_eigVect.eig')    
    joblib.dump(meanVal, './pca_args_save/meanVal.mean')   
    return lowDDataMat, reconMat


def autoset_eigNum(eigValues, rate=0.99):

    eigValues_sorted = sorted(eigValues, reverse=True)
    eigVals_total = eigValues.sum()
    for i in range(1, len(eigValues_sorted)+1):
        eigVals_sum = sum(eigValues_sorted[:i])     
        if eigVals_sum / eigVals_total >= rate:
            break
    return i
```

Comment: If your df is <20 rows long can you just go through the entire thing and check each entry with `isdigit`? From there you can find the problem entries and troubleshoot further from there. Quick [referece](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/isdigit) for `isdigit`

Answer (score 1):

It seemed that NumPy has some problem parsing your index row to float.

Try setting `skiprows = 1` in your `np.readtxt` command in order to skip the table header.

Comment: i try it but i get this error `ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 1969;17.93;3.96;0.88;7.38;19.86;25.45;5.34;19.21`

Comment: Please also set your delimiter according to your file. In your case, `delimiter= ";"` should do the job.